# Laravel Nested Array From MultiArray

Tags: arrays, nested

I have two different arrays and i want to combine them by grouping in categories;

My codes are below;

```
$categories = CarCarProperty::where('car_id',$arac->id)->pluck('car_property_category_id')->toArray();
      $properties = CarCarProperty::where('car_id',$arac->id)->wherein('car_property_category_id',$categories )->pluck('car_property_id')->toArray();
        $propertylist= [];
        $data= [];
        $data['category'] = [];
        $data['property'] = [];
        foreach($categories as $category ){

            $findcategory= CarPropertyCategory::where('id',$category)->first();

            $data['category'] = $findcategory->title;
            foreach($properties as $property){

               $findproperty = CarProperty::where('id',$property)->first();
                if($category->id == $findproperty->category->id){

                    $property= $findproperty ->title;
                    $data['properties'] = $property;

                }




            }

            $propertylist[] = $data;

        }




        $propertylist= collect($propertylist)->groupBy('category');
```

Shortly i must group the arrays by category and the hierachi must be like below;

```
array[    
category=> category_name,
    properties => [
    'property'=>property_name,
    'property'=>property_name,
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out at least as collection group by